# 'System.String' does not contain a property

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="product_header">
                <asp:Label ID="prodLabels" runat="server" >
                    <p><h4><%#Eval("Name") %></h4></p>
                </asp:Label>
    </div>

    <div class="left-col">
    <div class="img_product">

       <asp:Image ID="imgProduct" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Picture") %>' Width="200px" Height="200px"/>

    </div>
        </div>

        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

Code Behind:

 List<ProductModel> _prodObj = new List<ProductModel>();


                    _prodObj = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ProductModel>>().Result;

                    _prodObj.Where(x => x.PictureId != 0).Select(v => v.Picture = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(v.PictureBinary));
                    var _prodname = _prodObj.Where(x=>x.Id!=0).Select(i => i.Name=""+i.Name);
                    try
                    {
                        rptProducts1.DataSource = _prodname;
                        rptProducts1.DataBind();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        throw;
                   }
```

Issue while fetching data from the database.Want to display name and image of the product.While fetching records 'System.String' does not contain a property error is thrown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are databinding your repeater to a list of `String` as far as I can see.

This line will fetch a list of strings:

```
var _prodname = _prodObj.Where(x=>x.Id!=0).Select(i => i.Name=""+i.Name);
```

=> _prodname will be equal to a list of names.

And then, when you databind, you have this line:

```
Eval("Id")
```

Which is essentially saying: take the current object (which is a String) and print the `Id` property here. But since it's a String, it has no ID property, hence your exception.

So in short: bind to the list of products you want to display (the full objects, not just the names), or change your view to not use any properties that simply aren't there.

**UPDATE**
If you just want to display the one product, I'd advise you to select the right product server-side before databinding your control, like this for instance:

```
var _prodname = _prodObj.Where(x=>x.Id!=0 && x.Id == myId).FirstOrDefault().Select(i => i.Name=""+i.Name);
```

... where "myId" is of course the Id you're searching for.

And then, you should use a repeater to show the data. You can just use a Label like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" />

// and server side you would do this:
myLabel.Text = _prodName;
```

Comment: Thanks sir but than how to display name according to its id of a single product

Comment: So you just want to display the one product? Then a repeater isn't the way to do it, because that control is meant to be used with a list of items. I would just put a asp:label there, and change its Text property to set the name. I've updated my answer with an example. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> prodObj.Where(x=>x.Id!=0)
> ```

I suspect this is failing because `x` is a `string` and not what you expect it to be.

You need to do some debugging to identify what type `x` is, and then trace back to find where it stops being what you expect it to be.

Also,

> ```
> _prodObj.Where(x => x.PictureId != 0).Select(v => v.Picture = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(v.PictureBinary));
> ```

LINQ is evaluated lazily, unless something enumerates the result of the above expression nothing will be executed.

Comment: I think that last part is a bit misleading. The problem isn't lazy evaluation so much as it doesn't modify _prodObj but returns a new IEnumerable (which is then thrown away). I believe the OP probably expects _prodObj to be modified with that where and select.

Comment: Thanks sir but than how to display name according to its id of a single product

Comment: @MaheshGulve See Steven Lemmens' comment to his own answer, (Beyond that we're likely to need to see more of your code.)